# Unable to install pyret-lang using npm install

Tags: javascript, npm, error-handling, npm-install, pyret

I'm trying to install `Pyret-lang` from GitHub repo. I am on Node `v8.15.1` and `npm 6.4.1`.
`npm install` fails at `make phaseA-deps`. Run into a code error **ELIFECYCLE errno 2**.

https://github.com/brownplt/pyret-lang

```
4746 verbose npm  v6.4.1
4747 error code ELIFECYCLE
4748 error errno 2
4749 error pyret-lang@0.0.0 install: `make phaseA-deps`
4749 error Exit status 2
4750 error Failed at the pyret-lang@0.0.0 install script.
4750 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
4751 verbose exit [ 2, true ]
```

---

```
cp src/js/base/runtime.js build/phaseA/js/runtime.js
node -max-old-space-size=8192 lib/jglr/parser-generator.js src/js/base/pyret-grammar.bnf build/phaseA/js/pyret-grammar.js "../../../lib/jglr" "jglr/jglr" "pyret-base/js/pyret-parser"
Makefile:184: recipe for target 'build/phaseA/js/pyret-parser.js' failed
make: *** [build/phaseA/js/pyret-parser.js] Segmentation fault (core dumped)
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/amar/Pyret-lang/package.json'
npm WARN Pyret-lang No description
npm WARN Pyret-lang No repository field.
npm WARN Pyret-lang No README data
npm WARN Pyret-lang No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! pyret-lang@0.0.0 install: `make phaseA-deps`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the pyret-lang@0.0.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: It's really bizarre that it *segfaults*. I would try a node version update first – I don't think there's any reason it wouldn't work on the 8.x you describe, but updating it could help. Also, what platform are you running on?

Comment: Node version is keeping in line with the 32 bit recommendation. I used NVM for the install. The install folders are slightly different from a direct install of node.
`/home/amar/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/lib/node_modules`
 I am on Ubuntu 16.04.06 LTS.

Comment: Sorry, I'm missing something – what's the 32-bit recommendation?

Comment: I mean to say node > 8.x versions are not available for 32 bit install. My machine is 32 bit.